# Connection to CRM Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to connect to the CRM SQL server from a C# Project in Visual Studio.

I have already added the Database as a Data Connection, but I do not know how to connect to it in the code and how to make a sample query (e.g. `SELECT * FROM FilteredAccount`)

Any suggestion?

Comment: this is a very fundamental question, I'd recommend researching and learning the basics of ADO.NET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect to your local SQL Server Express, and connect to the "Northwind" database, and read the top 5 customers from the "Customers" table, you'd have to do something like this:

```
string connectionString = "server=(local)\SQLExpress;database=Northwind;integrated Security=SSPI;";

using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   string queryStatement = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM dbo.Customers ORDER BY CustomerID";

   using(SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStatement, _con))
   {
      DataTable customerTable = new DataTable("Top5Customers");

      SqlDataAdapter _dap = new SqlDataAdapter(_cmd);

      _con.Open();
      _dap.Fill(customerTable);
      _con.Close():

   }
}
```